# Can't install apk

Tags: android, apk

Like the title says I'm trying to make a private Bs server and I'm tried to change the ip in the brawlstars apk but I'm getting an error when try to install, anyone can help?

I did signed the file and changed the sha1-digests in the meta-inf

The device specs where I'm tried to install from:
Android 13 api 33
Arch: armebi-v7a

Error:

```
adb: failed to install C:\Users\KÃ³kaiBalÃ¡zs_1vhydzi\Desktop\SignApk-master\bs-signed.apk: Failure [-124: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]
```

Apk: [Download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/8nxs44duk09jf1u/bs-signed.apk/file)

Comment: The APK file is simply defect. If you have modified it using with apktool then see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/78159986/150978 If not you could try to modify it and recompile it using apktool and thus make it usable.